# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Last night I upgraded my Visual Studio 2017 to the latest version 15.7.0. Since then **all** my projects are not running any more. 
The error I am getting:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried adding manually a referece to the DLL, I am still getting the error

Comment: I got the same issue with a brand new project using VS 2017 v 15.7. I added a master page and a simple page, nothing more.

I zipped the project and uploaded it here http://www.corobori.com/sos/WebApplication2.zip

Comment: That same sample project works just fine on my spare machine running VS 2017 v 15.4

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by 1) updating Visual Studio from 15.7.0 to 15.7.1 2) repairing the installation